# Getting unexpected character from scraping with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, css, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract the text inside [this html structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcsBp.png).

I have the following Beautiful Soup code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

def url_get_text(url):
    text=""
    page = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
    text = [p for p in soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'intro'}).getText()]
    sleep(0.75)
    return text

texts=[]
url = https://editorialorsai.com/el_viejo_folletin_y_las_nuevas_tecnologias/
texts.append([url_get_text(url)])
print("Text:" + str(texts))
print("Text length:" + str(len(texts)))
```

This is the output I get:

```
Text:[[['\xa0']]]
Text length:1
```

I don't understand why I'm getting a non-breaking space character instead of the text in the structure.

Answer (score 0):

The data is loaded dynamically via Ajax call. You can use `requests` module to simulate this call.

For example:

```
import json
import requests


def url_get_text(url):
    page = requests.get(url).json()

    # uncomment this to print all data:
    # print(json.dumps(page, indent=4))
    return page['entradilla']

url = 'https://editorialorsai.com/el_viejo_folletin_y_las_nuevas_tecnologias/'
api_url = 'https://hernancasciari.com/apis/articulus/v1/blogs/blog_orsai/articulos/{}'

t = url_get_text(api_url.format(url.split('/')[-2]))
print(t)
print()
print("Text length: {}".format(len(t)))
```

Prints:

```
Ayer di por finalizada la primera etapa de un experimento de ficción llamado Más respeto, que soy tu madre, en el que usé el recurso de la bitácora (una herramienta de publicación cronológica de contenidos en internet) para contar una historia costumbrista desde la subjetiva de un ama de casa argentina de clase media. La repercusión del proyecto fue tan asombrosa que me gustaría compartir algunos detalles con el lector.

Text length: 423
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
I really don't know much about web programming, so I wanted to ask you what are the cues that allow you to recognize that the data was loaded dynamically with AJAX?

Comment: @Francisco If you print the data returned from the server, for example `print(soup)` and the tags you're looking for aren't there, the data is most probably loaded via Ajax.

Comment: Ok, great. Thanks again for your help.